# Cassandra Opscenter error

Tags: java, linux, cassandra, opscenter

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.  
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found 
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
```

While executing opscenter for cassandra cluster it gives above error.I got some workaournd on hashlib but didn't work.The installed openssl OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips, i changed to OpenSSL 0.9.8zc & added /usr/local/ssl/lib to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH still gives above problem.Its linux OS. What i am missing while running ./opscenter -f i am getting hash error.

Comment: Which version of Opscenter are you using?  Was Opscenter installed from the tarball or from a package?  Also, which distribution and version of Linux are you using on this machine instance?

Comment: @respringer Opscenter: 5.0.2 & linux is : RedHat 6.I checked with Ubuntu no issue it runs fine but here it fails. Opscenter from tarball running it from bin ./opscenter -f